# 2 wifi adapters in order by hardware

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, wireless-access-point

Hi Everyone so i have two wifi devices, one is realtek and one is the BCM43438 (rpi onboard)

Due to the realtek having issues supplying an access point I have to have the rpi onboard device serving AP and the realtek connection to a wireless network.

but i have a problem, linux loads them in no particular order.

I can fix this by specific mac addresses by using the following lines in the following file:

## /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

```
#edimax
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", 
ATTR{address}=="{MAC_ADDRESS_OF_REALTEK}", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="wlan0"
#onboard
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", 
ATTR{address}=="{MAC_ADDRESS_OF_ONBOARD}", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="wlan1"
```

but i really need this to be by "device" not by "mac" address as i plan to clone these a lot and i don't want to change the mac on each one.

and help given is so greatly appreciated!
MooseH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man udev` for rule syntax and how to deal with parent attributes, `udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/class/net/wlan0` etc. to see the attributes for your WLAN devices. Pick the attributes you like (PCI device, vendor/device id, whatever) and edit the rules.

Comment: awesome answer got me on the perfect track, thanks!